# Drop-down menu moving h2/getting "a" to be centered

Tags: html

I wrote a website design that has a drop-down menu and a page that has a link to my facebook page. Every time you move your mouse over the drop-down menu, however, the h2 tag moves to the right. How do I get this to not happen?

Also, how can I center the "a" tag that contains the link to my FB page to be centered underneath the h2 tag? Here is the code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset = "UTF-8">
    <title>practice</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="practice.css">

    <style type="text/css">
    h1{
        color: black;
    }

    body {
        background-color: lightgrey;
    }

    #top_nav li:hover ul{
        display: block;
        position: relative;

    }

    #top_nav {
        display: block;
        position: relative;
        background-color: grey;
        border: 1px solid black;
        font: bold 16px Sans-serif;
        height: 40px;
        width: 1000px;
        margin: 0px auto;
    }

    #top_nav ul{
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 5px;
    }

    #top_nav li {
        position: relative;
        float: left;
        list-style-type: none;
    }

    #top_nav ul:after{
        content: ".";
        display: block;
        height: 0px;
        clear:both;
        visibility: hidden;
        border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    }

    #top_nav li a {
        text-decoration: none;
        display: block;
        color: white;
        border-right: 1px solid black;
        padding: 5px 25px;
    }

    #top_nav ul ul {
        position: absolute;
        display: none;
        left: 0px;
        background-color: grey;

    }

    #top_nav ul ul li {
        border: 1px solid black;
        width: 99%;
    }

    #top_nav ul ul li a {
        border-right: none;
    }

    a {
        text-decoration: none;
        text-align: center;
    }

    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <h1 style="text-align: center">This is practice</h1>

    <div id = "top_nav">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="contact.html">contact us </a></li>
            <li><a href="about.html">about us</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="history.html">our history</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <p></p>
    <h2 style="text-align: center">Facebook Page</h2>
    <a href="#" target="_blank">my profile</a>
</body>
</html>
```

I have also uploaded the website at: html.freeoda.com in case you want to see the code working in real time. Just navigate to the "contact" page.
Thanks!

Comment: Just a suggestion but rather than try and reinvent the wheel use a pre-existing solution: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#dropdowns

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just fix it change:

```
#top_nav li:hover ul{
    display: block;
    position: relative;
}
```

To:

```
#top_nav li:hover ul{
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Basically what you were doing by changing it to relative was placing it back in the DOM to effect other elements, by using absolute positioning it doesnt interact with other elements the same way.

But like i said in my comment there is no reason to reinvent the wheel. Twitters bootstrap has a very nice working solution: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#dropdowns

As for centering the a tag you have a couple of options, the one i recommend would be just to make it a block element and center the text:

```
<a href="#" target="_blank" id="fb-profile-link">my profile</a>
```

Add an id to make it easily selectable then add:

```
#fb-profile-link{
    display: block;
    text-align:center;
}
```

By default the a tags have a display of `inline` by changing it to block the element will automatically take up the width of its container. In this case the body of the document. Then using the `text-align` property we just center the text in that.